# Is it possible to scan the image using Android Emulator?

Tags: appium

Right now, we are using Open CV framework for scanning purpose in Android. 
Is it possible to scan the image using Android Emulator?

Comment: Scan as in you wanna scan image (like some photoscan and save it as image) or recognise what is in the image (Like picking the image from the gallery and process it, edit it??)

Answer (score -1):

Nope its not possible. You have to use the actual device in order to get the advantage of device capabilities.

Emulators can Emulate (or simulate) nearly real-world experience but they cannot cover everything. So, you have to use real device.